# Why is this conditional formatting still highlighting cells that don't meet the condition?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to apply Conditional formatting applying to column K (range K2:K1001). What I want to do is to highlight each cell in the column if it's date value (e.g., "6/1/2016") is less than a date in each cell in K2:K10001 minus 7 days.

How do I make this happen across all cells in column K all at once without having to write a formula (or something equivalent) one cell at a time?  Basically I want to work as I do in Excel - write one formula - then copy/paste down the entire column.

Comment: Have you tried a date a little closer to home. eg. `6/2/2020`? It's just that `6/2/2100` is out-of-range for many date systems, so could be returning a value that does satisfy `< (today() - 7)` after all. However, this is a guess, google-sheets might have a better date implementation.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what exactly your formula is. A link to shared spreadsheet where the problem occurs would also be helpful.'

Comment: Formulas for conditional formatting could be checked as usual formulas, they behave the same. Enter in any cell `="6/2/2100"< today() -7` and the result is `false`. Need a sample file or more details to help you. I'll downvote the question till it's not clear how to solve it.

Comment: @Meta I prefer to ask anonymously without linking to a named sheet.  Max Makhrov, I think this is much more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Docs help gives good instruction on [how to make Conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en), for your case Custom formula is:

```
=$k2<today()-7
```

Comment: thanks, my question is for each date in the cell in the range K2:K1001.  Each cell in column K will have a date and I want to hightlight it according to the "today()-7" criteria. How do I do this?

Comment: select `K2:K1001` → make Conditional formatting → your formula → `=$k2<today()-7`